# Postgres-XL does not support TRIGGER yet

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, postgres-xl

When I use

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

I get this error:

```
Postgres-XL does not support TRIGGER yet 
The feature is not currently supported
```

I am using Postgres-XL 10r1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Then you cannot use that extension with Postgres-XL.

Comment: which version should i use? are all version is not supported?

Comment: You'd have to ask Postgres-XL, but I think none of their versions supports triggers.